# ODBC Connection to Access 2016 Failing from Python with pyodbc

Tags: python, odbc, connection-string, pyodbc, ms-access-2016

My code:

```
connection_string = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\\Users\\Bob-Admin\\Documents\\MyDatabase.accdb;')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
```

My error:

```
('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Environment Details:

1. Windows 10
2. Office 2016
3. 64-bit Access 2016
4. 64-bit Python 3.7.3
5. 64-bit and 32-bit Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
6. pyodbc 4.0.27

I've looked through all the older connection issues posts, none match these environmental parameters. Any new thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

FYI just because Microsoft Access Database Driver shows up in your ODBC Data Source Administrator window does not necessarily mean it's installed. I went ahead and downloaded from Microsoft website; magically, it began working. Solved.

Comment: It's installed, but in such a way that only the Office apps can use it. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb).

Comment: Thanks Gord! Good to know